# Stop VS Code from opening a web browser window when I build my project in the console

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code

I created a Hello World application using [this](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript) tutorial.

When I build the application from the terminal in VS Code typing `npm start` VS Code or npm, no clue who, will open a new browser window... without even an url or anything in it.

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening? i.e. if I type in the console `npm start` I do not mind what happens but I want to avoid to open automatically a window of my browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to run `BROWSER=none npm start` or create an `.env` file with `BROWSER=none`. Refer to [Advanced Configuration](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#advanced-configuration) of create-react-app official docs

Comment: This works. How did you find it out? And do you know if I can set that in the already existing config files?

Do you know, is it VS Code or npm launching the browser?

Comment: In the official docs of create-react-app, you can find it. You can use the `.env` file or another solution is to change the start task on the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `.env` file at the root of your project and insert the `BROWSER=none npm start` property.

An alternative would be direct throught terminal, like this: `set BROWSER=NONE && npm start`

[Here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/873) you can see the discussing about that.

Answer (score 0):

The following solutions did not work.
What worked for me was to uncheck the checkbox "Start web browser on launch" located in project properties window (opened from Solution explorer)
[image]